# Why is the last ACK needed in TCP four way termination

Tags: tcp, layer4

As per title. Sorry if this is a duplicate question, but in the numerous posts online, I could only find how a connection is torn down, but not (convincingly) why it is done in such a way.

---

```
1. A -----FIN-----> B
2. A <----ACK------ B
3. A <----FIN------ B
4. A -----ACK-----> B        <====== Why is this one necessary?

======if 3 or 4 lost=======
5. A <....FIN...... B
6. A .....ACK.....> B
```

It seems B can shutdown the socket as soon as it sends out its `FIN(3)` because

1. if the `FIN(3)` is not lost, all is well.
2. if it is lost, A can timeout anyway and close the connection. One can argue that if this does happen, A will have to wait for a very long time. But B bears some risk with this last `ACK(4)` as well. Suppose the connection suddenly goes down (though with low probability) right after A sends out the last `ACK(4)`, causing B unable to receive it. Then B will have to wait and timeout, too. Since both approaches are flawed, why not save this last `ACK`?

---

**My guess**

I think the only exception is that there is a reasonably high chance of packet loss such that both `FIN(3)` and `ACK(4)` won't arrive.

If `FIN(3)` is lost, receiving nothing back from A, B will resend its new `FIN(5)`.

Similarly, if `ACK(4)` is lost, B will think that its `FIN(3)` is lost and resend the `FIN(5)` as well. A, though having sent out `ACK(4)`, is supposed in the `TIME-WAIT` status, will hopefully receive this new `FIN(5)` and resend an `ACK(6)`.

It seems only if the scenario described above happens reasonably frequently, will the last `ACK(4)` have a significant impact.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin The answers so far are helpful, but did not address the question directly.

Comment: Ok. We are working on the year-end cleanup to see how many open questions with answers we can get completed. If you get an answer, you can answer yourself and accept it. The question of why the last ACK is required is just that nay FIN only means that the sender of the FIN is done sending, and it must still be open to receive more segments, and it must resend any unacknowledged segments. Each side is a peer (client/server is an application concept), and both sides must agree that everything is done.

Comment: In my diagram, A already sent a FIN and received the ACK from B, so I suppose B does not need to remain open for more data.But the "resend any unacknowledged segments" argument is inspiring. Suppose B has 3 packets to send. Is B allowed to send its own FIN before receiving A's ACK for packet 3?

Comment: "_Suppose B has 3 packets to send. Is B allowed to send its own FIN before receiving A's ACK for packet 3?_" B will not send a FIN until it is done sending everything it has to send. One side cannot force the other the end. If one side sends FIN, it can only resend segments (_not_ packets) and ACKs to acknowledge any segments it receives from the side not finished sending. Each side must acknowledge it understands the other side is done sending when it has received a FIN. Remember, they are peers.

Comment: The acknowledgment number in the ACK segment is for all data _prior_ to the the acknowledgment number. The acknowledgement number, itself, is the number of the _next_ expected data.

Comment: To rephrase and confirm I understand it correctly: If B has 3 data segments to send, after the connection is established, the protocol allows B to send segment 3 and then immediately its FIN before receiving A's ACK-3. Consequently, after B sends out its FIN, it should wait for not only A's ACK-3, but also A's ACK-FIN, to make sure A understands all data is sent. Is that right?

Answer (score 9):

```
A -----FIN-----> B
FIN_WAIT_1       CLOSE_WAIT
A <----ACK------ B
FIN_WAIT_2

(B can send more data here, this is half-close state)

A <----FIN------ B
TIME_WAIT        LAST_ACK
A -----ACK-----> B
|                CLOSED
2MSL Timer
|
CLOSED
```

The ACK to a FIN is required because the end sending the FIN will retransmit it until it receives an ACK. So, the question is, why TCP keeps sending the FIN if not ACK is received? My understanding is that given that a connection may be in a half-close state, the side that is receiving the last FIN (A in your diagram) may be waiting for data "indefinitely" wasting resources in that end when no more data will be received. B needs to be sure that A received the FIN (and closes the connection), hence it requires an ACK.

**Edit**

To be more precise about half-close. In your example, A can close its side of the connection sending the first FIN and receiving the first ACK, but B can keep sending more data at will for any period of time before closing the connection and sending the last FIN. So, the time between the first FIN/ACK sequence and the second one can't be determined or timed-out. A needs the last FIN to be sure B has closed its side of the connection.

**Edit 2**

What happen if the last FIN from B to A is lost? Then, B will not receive the ACK and will retransmit the FIN until it receives an ACK. So, A will eventually get the FIN and transition to the TIME_WAIT state.

```
A -----FIN-----> B
FIN_WAIT_1       CLOSE_WAIT
A <----ACK------ B
FIN_WAIT_2

(B can send more data here, this is half-close state)

A  (Lost)X<--FIN------ B
FIN_WAIT_2       LAST_ACK
                 (timeout waiting for ACK)
A <----FIN------ B
TIME_WAIT
A -----ACK-----> B
|                CLOSED
2MSL Timer
|
CLOSED
```

What happen if the last ACK is lost? Then, B will think that A did not receive the FIN and will retransmit the FIN. From B point of view this is the same as if the FIN was lost, from A point of view this different since A now is in the TIME_WAIT or CLOSED state. When A receives the new FIN from A if it is in the TIME_WAIT state it will send the ACK again.

```
A -----FIN-----> B
FIN_WAIT_1       CLOSE_WAIT
A <----ACK------ B
FIN_WAIT_2

(B can send more data here, this is half-close state)

A <----FIN------ B
TIME_WAIT        LAST_ACK
A -----ACK-->X(Lost)   B
TIME_WAIT        LAST_ACK
                 (timeout waiting for ACK)
A <----FIN------ B
A -----ACK-----> B
|                CLOSED
2MSL Timer
|
CLOSED
```

If A is in the CLOSED state it will send a RESET, in either case B will be able to close its side of the connection.

```
A -----FIN-----> B
FIN_WAIT_1       CLOSE_WAIT
A <----ACK------ B
FIN_WAIT_2

(B can send more data here, this is half-close state)

A <----FIN------ B
TIME_WAIT        LAST_ACK
A -----ACK-->X(Lost)   B
TIME_WAIT        LAST_ACK
|
2MSL Timer
|
CLOSED
                 (timeout waiting for ACK)
A <----FIN------ B
A -----RST-----> B
                 CLOSED
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Your reasoning is that B has to know A has received `FIN(3)` so that A will close its connection. But following this same reasoning, to guarantee that B will close its connection as well, A had better get an extra `ACK` from B to know B indeeds receives A's `ACK(4)`. And this falls back to the two-armies problem mentioned by @JeanPierre. However this extra `ACK` is not required by the TCP protocol. But why is this the case?

Comment: @wlnirvana Please see my update. Let me know if that clarifies your doubts.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. For the mechanism you illustrated to work significantly better than my proposal (getting rid of the last `ACK`), I guess the packet loss rate should not be very low?

Comment: i don't see how you can get rid of the last ACK. Please, recall that A can't timeout waiting for a FIN and B should receive the ACK to stop resending the FIN.

Comment: Why "A can't timeout waiting for a FIN"? What if the physical cable is unplugged? Will A wait infinitely?

Comment: Yes, if cable is unplugged or no data is received while in the ESTABLISHED state, connection in A will remain in that state "forever". Anyways it is different to timeout than to explicitly signal that the connection is being closed. The protocol is designed like that because explicit notification is required.

Comment: That makes sense, but does not sound very intuitive. Just to confirm, if an attacker  establishes a TCP connection with a server, causing both to be in the ESTABLISHED state. Then he/she unplugs the cable (or maybe kill the process/reboot the OS). The socket on the server side will stay in ESTABLISHED state and never be released? This seems to allow some easy attack.

Comment: If you think that TCP is working that way since the 70's this is not really an issue to worry about. Even when there are some kind of attacks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris_(computer_security) well designed services can avoid this kind of problem, for example using reverse proxies like Nginx, using firewalls, designing protocols and services where server always disconnect clients after some idle time, etc. By the way, regardless of this detail, if you think that my answer answer your question please accept it.

Comment: You have provided a lot of helpful information, and I am thankful for that. Unfortunately, my question has not been addressed satisfactorily. I was not asking **HOW** is TCP designed, but **WHY** is it designed like that. You primarily explained the former (eg. last ACK is needed because "explicit notification is required"), but now the **WHY** part.

Comment: The first paragraph of this answer (as of Oct 2021) seems to answer directly the question. I came here with same question as yours @wlnirvana and now I'm confused if this answer is complete or not. What would be missing?

Answer (score 1):

*There are 2 pairs of FIN/ACKs because in TCP each direction of the stream is closed separately*. When A sends a FIN to B, it means that A will not send any more data to B. The connection can remain open and B can send as many data as it wants. Once B sends the second FIN, the data stream is closed in both directions and connection can be terminated.

One example where this could be useful is HTTP (actually was HTTP a long time ago, with modern web-pages its more complicated). A client sends the server HTTP request containing requested URL. Then the client can send the FIN. The server knows that it will not receive any data from the client and clear TCP buffer / potentially some other connection state. The server then sends the web-page over this connection.

To deal with lost FINs and corresponding ACKs, TCP is required to keep some of the connection state for some predefined time after both FINs are sent (i think it is about 2min, but it should be in TCP standard). In particular, if the sender of the FIN does not receive an ACK, it re-transmits the FIN.

I think i saw a function in Linux socket API that only closes outgoing stream, i.e., you can still read from the socket but can't write to it. I can't remember what it is called :(

Answer (score 0):

TCP provides a reliable transmission service.  This includes each party knowing it has received **all** the data the other intended to transmit.  In your example, A won't know it has received all B's data until it receives the FIN. B is going to retransmit the FIN, so that it knows that A knows all data has been transmitted.

As a side note, this also implies A needs to "stay here" after it has sent its ACK to B's FIN: when B retransmits the FIN, if A's gone, B won't get any ACK (and possibly a RST) and so cannot guarantee A knows it has received all data.  A stays some time in the TIME_WAIT state to ACK such retransmitted FINs.  Strictly, it would need to stay there until it knows B has received its ACK but that's an unsolvable problem often dubbed the "two-armies" problem.

Comment: I understand what you said and how TCP is designed, but my question is why it is designed as it is. As the two-armies problem you mentioned, it is **theoretically** unsolvable, thus impossible to be 100% reliable. For example if the network fails in step 4, right after A sends the `ACK` and before B receives it, B will end up retrying the `FIN` infinitely. So why the `ACK`?

Comment: @wlnirvana It will not retry infinitely but will give up at some point (this is true for all the segments to be ack'ed not just the FINs).  In this case, B can't be sure the transfer was successfull. When the network fails no reliable tranfer can be performed, but if it does not then: 1. receiving the FIN, A knows it has received all data so the transfer is successfull; 2. receiving the ACK, B knows A knows it has received all data, so it also know the transfer is successfull.  If one of these two segments are lost they  will be retransmitted.

Comment: But even without "1. receiving the FIN" (i.e. the FIN is lost and B has closed the connection on its side), A still knows that the data previously transmitted were successful. Though A is not sure if more data will come, it can wait up to a certain amount of time and then close its connection.

Comment: Imagine the message sent by B is `Transfer the following amount to Mr X: $ 10000` but A receives `Transfer the following amount to Mr X: $ 10`. A wants to know it has received the whole message.

Comment: Where does this message `Transfer ...` come from? It seems you are suggesting the case where the `FIN` packet itself carries data. While this is possible with TCP, we can easily design another protocol (let's call it `TNTCP` for `TNTCP is Not TCP`) that forbids `FIN+data`. In other words, if B wants to say the message `Transfer ...`, B must send it and receive the `ACK` before B sends out a "clean" `FIN`. And with `TNTCP`, B closes its connection as soon as the `FIN` is sent out. In this case do we still need the last `ACK`?